# How to get the size of a dynamically loaded swf with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash

I want to get the dimensions of a dynamically loaded flash object and resize a DIV accordingly to it. I can't use a server side language to do it.

I've tried searching about loading and reading the header portion of a SWF file to get it's dimensions with javascript but came up empty.

Is this remotely possible/feasible?

Thanks in advance, J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [the discussion here](http://groups.google.com/group/swfobject/browse_thread/thread/b52016ad28b74d09?pli=1), you need to create another swf (call it A) that loads the swf you want to embed (call it B), and read the dimension of B using A's `Loader`'s `contentLoaderInfo` to get the `width` and `height` of B. Finally tell the value to JS using A's `ExternalInterface`.